# In HTML, How can I suppress the line feed after a ul before a li

Tags: html, css

When I follow a ul or ol tag with an li tag, my browsers (FF & Chrome) always put a line feed between them.

How can I suppress the line feed? I can't find a relevant attribute in the W3 docs.

All the better if I can do it with CSS.

Comment: Have you tried modifying the `margin` or `padding` properties? Have you tried inspecting the elements and looking at their box model?

Comment: I don't think a line feed would be the problem, since whitespace is mostly ignore in HTML. Could the problem be margin or padding?

Comment: Who upvoted this question?!

Answer (score 2):

Some elements get default margin or padding from the browser.

For instance the paragraph has padding, the headings have margin, the ul has padding and margin and list style etc.

Make sure for ul and li to override padding and margin like this:

```
ul, li {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

Comment: I added that CSS. It moved the li lines all the way to the left, but it did not remove the line feed  between the ul and the first li.

Comment: Then an other css file or style is overwriting yours, try to inspect that element, or use `!important` but always try to avoid important tag in normal surcomstances.

Comment: I have not linked to any other css files, and I have no attributes in the tags themself. Even if there were included css files, shouldn't my local css take precedence over everything but attributes in the tags?

Comment: I looked at the css in firebug. It showed all the padding and margins = 0. There must be some other attribute governing the line feed.

Comment: Is there any `:after` or `:before` set? Otherwise i cant think of anything else right now

Comment: I haven't set any, and I don't see any in the firebug display.

Comment: I guess I'll just have to switch to <dd> and <dt> which work fine,

Comment: You could check line-height on li, but i doubt you would overlook that. Do you have an online version?

Comment: Rens: line-height doesn't change the spacing between the <ul> and the first <li>, just between <li>s

Comment: I understand, but I can't really help you further without having the URL of with the example problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's up to the browser how the list is rendered.  Example: Chrome's default is to use a margin and setting the margin to 0 will close the gap you speak of:

```
<ul style="margin: 0">
...
</ul>
```